# Why cant I initialize state with props? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im having a headcache with this and i dont know whats wrong with this, i have a parent component that will pass props to the childs component, in the parent component I run this function in `componentDidMount`

```
requestPermission = async () => {
        try {
            const permission = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
                [
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                ],
            );
            if (permission["android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED 
                && permission["android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                try {
                    let tracks = [];
                    let tracks_object = []; 
                    tracks = await MusicFiles.getAll({
                        cover: true,
                    });
                    let length = tracks.length;
                    for (i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
                        tracks_object.push(new Tracks_info(tracks.results[i]));
                    }
                    this.setState({tracks: tracks_object}, () => this.init_player());
                }catch(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            }else {
                this.requestPermission();
            }
        }catch (error) {
            alert(error)
        }
    };
```

heres the callback that is init_player:

```
init_player = async () => {
        
        try {
            if (this.random) {
                let tracks = this.random_queue();
                await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
                await TrackPlayer.add(tracks);
                this.setState({random_tracks: tracks, first_id_song: tracks[0].id, last_id_song: tracks[tracks.length - 1].id});
            }else {
                let tracks = this.state.tracks;
                await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
                await TrackPlayer.add(tracks);
                this.setState({first_id_song: tracks[0].id, last_id_song: tracks[this.state.tracks.length - 1].id})
            }
        }catch(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
}
```

and heres the render of parent:

```
render() {
    
    const props = {
        tracks: this.state.tracks, //this props is used to print the list 
        info_track: (this.random) ? this.state.random_tracks: this.state.tracks, //this props is used to set the queue either shuffle is active or not
        playing: this.state.playing,
        play_selected_music: this.play_selected_music.bind(this),
        get_time: this.get_time.bind(this),
        play: this.play_music.bind(this),
        pause: this.pause.bind(this),
        shuffle: this.shuffle.bind(this),
        next_song: this.next_song.bind(this),
        previous_song: this.previous_song.bind(this),
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Tracks {...props}></Tracks>
        </>
    )
}
```

then in the child component:

```
 state = {
    current_track_id: this.props.tracks[0]?.id,
    current_track: "",
    cover: "",
    show_icon: true,
    repeat: false,
    repeat_song_id: "",
    queue: false, 
    favorite: false,
}
```

when I print it in `componentDidMount` in child i get undefined, but using it as props in it works:

```
<Text>{this.props.tracks[0]?.id}</Text> //works print
<Text>{this.state.current_track_id}</Text> //doesnt print anything
```

only doesnt work when I try to set it to state in the child component

Comment: seems that you don't update the child state after you setting tracks in the parent component

Comment: @AlekseyPolonka, how can I update the child? because when I setState it should re render so the values of props must change and pass the new one, but it isnt happening

Comment: state = { current_track_id: this.props.tracks[0]?.id,....} you set the initial state values. When it happens the first time the value is undefined and it doesn't set a new value after the parent component receiving data. So, you can do next: 1) don't render the child component if the result isn't received; 2) re-set current_track_id prop on child component updates.